# Warning message (re. php) on the blog page

Tags: php, warnings

I've got a message below (the part "xyz/blog-name.com" was changed). That error message is not because of a Plug-in, as the message doesn't disappear even I stop all Plug-ins.

> "Warning: Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php' (this will
>   throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in
>   /home/*xyz/blog-name.com*/public_html/wp-content/themes/stingerplus-child/st-footer-content.php
>   on line 20"

The line 20 in my wp currently reads as fallows;

```
<a href="<?php//echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php// bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></a>
```

Can anyone please advise me what is wrong here...?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```php
<a href="<?php//echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php// bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></a>
```

The `<?php//` is the problem. PHP blocks are started with `<?php` but the code uses `<?php//`. Instead, change it to `<?php //`, or better yet, since `//` is meant to comment an entire line out, use `/* */` style commenting instead

Comment: fixed! Thanks so so much!

Comment: Awesome, if my answer answered your question could you mark it as the correct answer? It's the big tick under the voting arrows